# Element injected by ajax can't be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote the code to update the posts by using the ajax:

```
 $(function(){
   $('#loadFeed').bind('click',function(){ 
        $.getJSON('getData.php', function(json) {
            var output="<ul id='feedsList'>";

            for(var i=json.posts.length-1;i>=json.posts.length-31;i--){
                output+="<li class='post'>";
                output+="<div class='text'>"+json.posts[i].shortmsg+"</div>";         
                output+="</li>";
            }
            output+="</ul>"
            $(output).appendTo('.posts');
    });
  });
});
```

My html code:

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
        <div class="posts"></div>
 </div>
```

Then I wanted to click each post, the post will expand to show more detailed content.How can I do that? The code I wrote was:

```
$(function(){
     $('.text').bind('click',function(){
         $.getJSON('getData.php', function(json){   
         var thisID = this.id;      
         $(this).replaceWith("<div class='long_text'>"+json.posts[thisID].msg+"<div>"); 
         });
     });
});
```

But it didn't do anything.I was not sure if

```
var thisID = this.id;
```

worked or not. I changed my code a little bit:
`$(function(){
         $('.text').bind('click',function(){
             alert("Hello!")
         });
    });`

Still nothing happened!!I doubted if the .text was selected in the function.Anyone can help?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Let's say you have a container that exists before the dynamic content,

```
<div class="posts">
    <!--dynamic content here-->
</div>
```

then you attach a handler **once** to the existing container, and it will listen to the dynamic content's events

```
//"add listener for .text, attached on .post"
$('.posts').on('click','.text', function(){
    //do stuff when text is clicked    
});
```

Comment: Thanks!I did as what u said. But console said: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'. I did include the jquery as <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>. So why did that happen?

Comment: @YujunWu hmm.. it should exist in 1.7.  did you wrap your cod in `.ready()`? try using `jQuery` instead of `$` in case you are using another framework.

Comment: Got it work!!I somehow included an older version library after the 1.7.2 one,that's why the error came!

Comment: Just a follow-up question: I used $(this).attr("id") to get the id of the element in the dynamic content. But seems it didn't work. Are there any ways I can do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use .live() instead of .bind(). It will then stay alert for new elements appearing on the page.

Actually doc says:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()`'s special syntax.